How to Edit PDFs in React Native without Paid SDKs?
I'm working on a React Native project where I need to edit PDF files (for example, adding text, annotations, etc.) without using any paid SDKs. Most of the solutions I've come across require paid libraries like PSPDFKit, but I am looking for a free alternative or open-source library that allows PDF manipulation.
Here are the features I need:

Edit or annotate PDFs (adding text or image).
Text Selection
3.⁠ ⁠Text Highlight
4.⁠ ⁠Text Strikethrough
5.⁠ ⁠Text Underline
6.⁠ ⁠Signature (Add only) (color and font weight changing)
7.⁠ ⁠Add Text (Add and Drag/Drop in the page) (color and font size changing)

I've already tried libraries like react-native-pdf for viewing, but it doesn't support editing. Are there any good options that can help with this in React Native?
Thanks in advance!
I tried using the react-native-pdf library, which works well for viewing PDF files, but it doesn't have built-in support for editing or annotating PDFs. I was expecting to find a solution that would allow me to add text, highlights, or image to the PDF files, and then save the modified version.
